# Get elements by Name with html array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding new inputs dynamically. And I would also like to read values dynamically from them. My `championName` variable doesn't work in JS.

```
<form name="second_form" id="second_form" action="#" method="POST" style="margin: 0;"  >
    <div id="p_scents">
        <p>    
            <label for="p_scnts">
                <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" list="champions" name="champion[]" value=""  placeholder="Enter Champion's name">
                <datalist id="champions"></datalist>
                <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add General Change</a><a></a>
                <a href="#" id="addSpell"> Add Spell</a><a></a>

            </label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <br/><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


function val(doublechamp) {
    var championsWithExtraSpells = ["Aatrox", "Elise", "Fizz", "Heimerdinger", "Jayce", "Lee Sin", "Nidalee", "Rek'Sai","Twisted Fate"];
    var champion = this["champion[]"];
    var championName = document.getElementsByName("Champion[]").value;

    if($.inArray(championName, championsWithExtraSpells)==-1){
        var existsInArray = false;}
        else{
        var existsInArray = true;}

    d = document.getElementById("change[]").value;
    var spellname = document.getElementById("ttt");
    spellname.value=champions[""+championName+""][change(d, existsInArray)];

}
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail than just "*doesn't work*"?  What exactly do you expect your code to do?

Comment: I expect to get input in my championName variable

Answer (score 0):

Collection returned by **getElementsByName()** in the line, so just replace it.

**UPDATED**

**JS :**

Replace :

```
var championName = document.getElementsByName("Champion[]").value;
```

By :

```
for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByName("champion[]").length;i++)
     var championName = document.getElementsByName("champion[]")[0].value;
```

Now you can get all the inputs values.

Comment: it always shows the first input so e.g. I have 5 inputs and type sth in the first one and sth in the second one it will show in both the name from the first one

Comment: Adding for loop will do the job @Higeath.

Comment: http://89.69.172.125/test.php# When you add champions you can add spells and depending on which champion you chose it will input that champion's spells when switching between passive q w e r and I'm not sure how to get it working with more inputs (open console to check how it works)

Comment: I really can not fully understand what you want to do. i'm sorry :(

Comment: Did you mean `... ("champion[]")[i].value`?

Comment: not the logic you have in the test.php, i can see that with every champion we can add several spills (input for every spill), what you want to do now when you click on submit button ?

Comment: whenever someone changes this dropdown passive , q , w , e, r   function val() is executed in which I need variable with champions name

Comment: i can see the champions name in console when the dropdown passive change.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of changes you need to make:
- You're not invoking the function anywhere in the code you're showing

- you'll need to add an onChange clause to the input or an onsubmit to the form to check the values..
- the name of an element can't contain [] - so you should remove those from the name;

  ```
    <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" list="champions" name="champion" value=""  placeholder="Enter Champion's name">
  ```
- getElementsByName returns nodelist, not a single node (even if there's only one match).  If you make the following changes you'll get farther:

And in the script change these two lines:

```
    var championName = document.getElementsByName("champion");

    if($.inArray(championName[0].value, championsWithExtraSpells)==-1){
```